# How to print parameters from a "do for" cycle with Gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66545604/how-to-plot-on-the-same-graph-with-for-cycles-with-gnuplot/77606266#77606266) a quite helpful code for looping a fit through multiple data sets with the y-values in separate columns in one file. Each parameter is printed on the graph. Now, I was wondering how to extend the code so all parameters are listed in another .txt file.

I've tried to use the set print 'parameters.dat' and print a,b,c function, but this resulted in having only the parameters of the last fit. But I'd like to have the parameters of every fit in one file.
I'm using Gnuplot 5.4 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way gnuplot can print text to files is: (check `help set print`)

```
set print FILE                     # open file
    print sprintf("%g %g", x, y)   # or whatever...
set print                          # close file
```

So, if you want to print the fitting results of each iteration into a different file, you can add the following into the loop:

```
do for [i=1:3] {
    # do the fitting or whatever

    set print sprintf("FitResults%02d.txt",i)
        print sprintf("a = %g", a)
        print sprintf("b = %g", b)
        print sprintf("c = %g", c)
    set print   # close file
}
```

or all in the same file:

```
set print sprintf("FitResults.txt")
    do for [i=1:3] {
        # do the fitting or whatever

        print sprintf("Fit number: %d",i)
        print sprintf("a = %g", a)
        print sprintf("b = %g", b)
        print sprintf("c = %g", c)
        print ""    # empty line as separator
    }
set print   # close file
```

Answer (score 0):

The `set print` command takes an optional additional keyword `append`, which allows you to go back and add more to a previous output file.  So if there is some constraint in your script that prevents you from simply keeping a single output file attached to the print command for the entire duration of the script (perhaps the script uses `set print` for another purpose internally?) then you still have the option to re-open the original output file to append new lines for each iteration.

```
outfile = "multiplt_fits.out"
do for [col=colMin:colMax] {
    a=1; b=1; c=1             # some initial values
    fit f(x,a,b,c) $Data u 1:col via a,b,c
    ... some other stuff that uses `set print` ...
    set print outfile append
    print "Parameters fit for column ",col," : ", a,b,c
    unset print
}
```