# Gnuplot - How to make a legend with linespoints?

Tags: gnuplot, legend

I've been playing around with the code that was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66545604/how-to-plot-on-the-same-graph-with-for-cycles-with-gnuplot/77606266#77606266). Then, I was trying to add a legend with linespoints. This resulted in having the fit line being covered with points.

I've tried to set the title at different positions. But nothing resulted in what I was looking for. Shown in the picture[image: Results of 'with linespoints'] is the legend as I would want it. But the graph doesn't show only the data points but also points of the fit where I would like to have just the line.
If it matters, I've set up the code in LaTeX using 'gnuplottex' using gnuplot 5.4.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % German language
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs

\usepackage{booktabs,array} % Packages for tables

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath} % For typesetting math
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex} % External use of gnuplot
\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz} % Use terminal 'tikz'
\usepackage{tikz} % To call tikz inside a gnuplot graph
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=tikz, terminaloptions={color size 10cm,7cm}]
reset session
datafile = 'data.dat'
set multiplot layout 2,1
set print 'parameters.dat'

#____________________Set axis style________________________________


#________________Change the style lines____________________________
set style line 2 lc rgb '#000000' pt 7 lt 7 lw 1 # black 
set style line 3 lc rgb '#000000' pt 21 lt 7 lw 1 # black
set style line 4 lc rgb '#000000' pt 8 lt 7 lw 1 # black
set style line 5 lc rgb '#000000' pt 9 lt 7 lw 1 # black
set style line 6 lc rgb '#000000' pt 10 lt 7 lw 1 # black
set style line 7 lc rgb '#000000' pt 11 lt 7 lw 1 # black
set style line 8 lc rgb '#000000' pt 4 lt 7 lw 1 # black
set style line 9 lc rgb '#000000' pt 5 lt 7 lw 1 # black

#_____________Set the label for data points________________________
set key at 10.5,60                      # set position of legend
set key Left                                # set raggedleft
set key samplen 1 spacing 1.2 font ",8" # set fontsize and spacing
set key autotitle columnheader          # columnheader = legend

###1__________Define function and number of columns_________________________
f(x,a,b,c) = a*(x-b)**2 + c
colMin = 2
colMax = 5
set fit quiet nolog
array A[colMax]
array B[colMax]
array C[colMax]

do for [col=colMin:colMax] {
    a=1; b=1; c=1             # some initial values, sometimes 0 or NaN is not a good start
    fit f(x,a,b,c) datafile u 1:col via a,b,c
    A[col] = a;  B[col] = b;  C[col] = c
    
    print sprintf ('y%d: %.4f %.4f %.4f',col-1,A[col],B[col],C[col])
}

plot for [col=colMin:colMax] datafile u 1:col notitle ls col, \
     for [col=colMin:colMax] f(x,A[col],B[col],C[col]) ls col dt col \
         with linespoints title sprintf("$y%d$: a=%.2f, b=%.2f, c=%.2f",col-1,A[col],B[col],C[col])

\end{gnuplot}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your problem. In the title you are asking for `with linespoints` but in the text you are asking for a line without points? Instead of `with linespoints`, simply use `with lines`.

Comment: In the legend I'd like to see the linespoints but not in the plot. I've found a possible solution by adding 'pointinterval 100' to the style lines. But for me it seems more like a workaround...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the legend I'd like to see the linespoints but not in the plot

Well, the basic idea of the legend is to show what you see in the plot.
In your case, I assume you want to combine the original data (as filled points) and the fit (as line) into one legend entry since the points should be on (or near) the line.

With your suggestion `pointinterval 100` or whatever higher number for plotting the fit `with linespoints`, you will always see the first point.

Alternative suggestion: check `help keyentry`. With this, you are flexible and independent what you put into the key/legend, e.g. empty circle `pt 6` or filled circle `pt 7`, etc.

**Script:**

```
### different key/legend enty with keyentry
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1   2   4   2
2   5   1   3
3  10   0   6
4  17   1  11
5  26   4  18
EOD

f(x,a,b,c) = a*x**2 + b*x + c
N = 3
array A[N]; array B[N]; array C[N]
set fit  quiet nolog
do for [i=1:3] {
    a = b = c = 1   # initialize values
    fit f(x,a,b,c) $Data u 1:i+1 via a,b,c
    A[i] = a; B[i] = b; C[i] = c 
}

set key noautotitle out 

plot for [col=2:4] $Data u 1:col w p pt 7 lc col-1, \
     for [i=1:3] f(x,A[i],B[i],C[i]) w l lc i, \
     for [i=1:3] keyentry w lp pt 6 lc i ti sprintf("%d: a=%.2f, b=%.2f, c=%.2f",i,A[i],B[i],C[i])
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks and sorry for not being clear at the beginning!